# KMS: VT switcher

Tags: linux

I want to write a VT switcher so that I can change the active VT in cases where the system is unresponsive to Alt+F1...F8 (e.g., when uvesafb silently oopses). Which parts of the KMS API do I need to look into to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Your program already exists.

- `sudo chvt 1`
- `sudo chvt 7`

Take a look at chvt's source code if you want something different...